Inconsistent type inference for function parameters with default values
I'm facing a confusing issue with TypeScript's type inference when it comes to function parameters that have default values. In my implementation, I've defined a function type that includes a this context, and I expected TypeScript to infer the parameter types based on the default values I provided. However, the inference behavior appears inconsistent.
Specifically, I've noticed that while some functions infer their parameter types correctly, others default to any, which undermines type safety. For instance, one of my functions has a default parameter value, but instead of inferring the type as a specific number, TypeScript assigns it the type any.
To illustrate this issue, I've created a minimal example that reproduces the problem. Is this a known limitation in TypeScript or are there adjustments I can make to achieve the correct type inference?
type FnContext = {
    source: Record<string, any>;
};

type Fn<T = FnContext, P extends any[] = any[], R = void> = (this: T, ...params: P) => R;

type AnyFn = Record<string, Fn>;

type Options<F extends AnyFn> = {
    actions?: F;
};

function program<T extends AnyFn>(options: Options<T>) { }

program({
    actions: {
        foo(p = 2) {}, // Expected: (method) foo(this: FnContext, p?: number): void
                        // Actual: Inferred as (method) foo(this: FnContext, p?: any): void

        esp(p: number = 2) {}, // Expected: (method) esp(this: FnContext, p?: number): void
                                // Actual: Inferred as (method) esp(this: FnContext, p?: number): void

        bob(s: number) {} // Expected: (method) bob(this: FnContext, s: number): void
                           // Actual: Inferred as (method) bob(this: FnContext, s: number): void
    }
});

Playground
To address the inference issue, I tried changing the default parameter type to an empty tuple ([]) in the function definition, hoping this would clarify the expected types. Unfortunately, this led to errors in other functions, indicating that TypeScript was not handling the types as I anticipated.
I also experimented with conditional types to guide TypeScript's inference, but this approach didn't yield the desired outcome either. Ultimately, I expected TypeScript to automatically infer p in foo as number, but it was inferred as any, which is frustrating and compromises type safety.

TS doesn't have a way to look at both contextual typing for a function parameter as well as the default argument. This is a lack of feature, described at ms/TS#59643.  Your any is coming from any[] being the constraint (note, you're not using any of the generic type params in Fn, just their defaults). Does this fully address the question? If so I'll write an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Thank you for your input! I appreciate your insights on TypeScript's limitations. However, the inconsistent behavior I'm experiencing occurs even without the this context.
In my example, foo(p = 2) is inferred as (method) foo(p?: any): void, while esp(p: number = 2) correctly infers as (method) esp(p?: number): void. This inconsistency raises concerns about TypeScript's handling of default parameters.
If you have any further insights or workarounds, I’d love to hear them!

I'm not talking about "this context", I'm talking about contextual typing. The issue at ms/TS#59643 describes exactly your situation.  The workarounds are... annotate your parameters yourself, as you did in esp.  There might be other workarounds like... write your function outside of a contextual type, as shown here. Am I missing anything? Shall I proceed to an answer?

Thank you for the clarification! You're right; the issue relates to contextual typing, and ms/TS#59643 does describe my situation accurately. The suggested workarounds, such as annotating parameters directly (as I did with esp) or writing the function outside of a contextual type, seem to be the most viable options.
If you think there are additional workarounds or if I'm missing anything, please let me know. Otherwise, feel free to proceed with your answer!

@jcalz mate thanks to your suggestions, I think I got a workaround solution which fixed my problem. Thank You!

TypeScript currently lacks a mechanism to consider both the  default argument and the contextual type of a function parameter when inferring its type.
So if you have a context-free function parameter with a default argument, TypeScript will use the default argument to type the parameter:
const foo = function (this: FnContext, p = 2) { }
// const foo: (this: FnContext, p?: number) => void

and if you have a contextual type for a function parameter but no default argument, TypeScript will use the contextual type to type the parameter:
const bar: (this: FnContext, p?: number) => void =
    function (p) { }
    //        ^? (parameter) p: number | undefined

but in the case where there is both a contextual type and a default argument, TypeScript will essentially ignore the default argument and just look at the contextual type, which is unhelpful if that context is a generic type parameter that itself needs to be inferred:
function oops<T>(cb: (x: T) => void) { }
oops((x = 1) => { })
//    ^? (parameter) x: unknown

Here the callback parameter x was contextually typed from (x: T) => void. But T was not inferred from anywhere, so it fell back to its constraint which is implicitly unknown.  So x is of type unknown despite the default.

This inability to consider the default argument in the presence of a contextual type is considered a missing feature. It is reported at microsoft/TypeScript#59643 (the issue is filed as if it were a bug, but it was classified as a possible improvement and thus a missing feature). It's tagged as Help Wanted, so if you want to see this changed, you might consider writing your own pull request that implements it.
Until and unless that happens you'll have to work around it.  The easiest workaround is what you've already done: just annotate the parameters you care about.  Or you could use the default argument in a context-free location like foo above, and then just use that instead of an inline function:
program({
    actions: {
        foo, // <-- this is using the foo defined above
    }
});

There are undoubtedly other possible workarounds, but in any case, you'll have to intentionally resolve the tension between contextual typing and default arguments.
Playground link to code
